# How to find the element through Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using Selenium with PHP WebDriver. I am trying to click on a link in the navbar, which appears in the HTML as follows:

```
<li class=""><a href="javascript:;" showpage="cards"><i class="zzdi zzdi-closed-caption zzdi-hx-fw"></i> User Cards</a></li>
```

I am trying to select the element then click it. However, when I try using xpath as follows:

```
//a[@showpage="cards"]
```

or

```
//*[@showpage="cards"]
```

I get the following error:

> no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"/*[@showpage="cards"]"}   (Session info:
>   chrome=70.0.3538.110)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233
>   (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux
>   4.15.0-43-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info:
>   host: 'ubuntu', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '4.15.0-43-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_191' Driver
>   info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=LINUX,
>   acceptSslCerts=false,
>   goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:43431},
>   acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false,
>   rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.43.600233
>   (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),
>   userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.Teyqo7},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=70.0.3538.110,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   367080a50b61c75a8c16a17b954a5972
>   *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=/*[@showpage="cards"]}

Any help on how to use xpath or how to use any other selection method that would enable me to click on the link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to wait for element to be able to click it:

```
$driver->wait()->until(
  WebDriverExpectedCondition::elementToBeClickable(WebDriverBy::xpath('//a[@showpage="cards"]')))->click();
```

Comment: This error happens as an exception when attempting to do driver->findElement. The script doesn't even reach the wait() part...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that didn't work. I get "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeOutException in /var/www/html/wioc/sdk/ext/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/WebDriverWait.php:84" after the command. When I do a getPageSource I can clearly see that link appearing in the HTML.

Comment: @Idan , Can you check whether link located inside an `<iframe>`

Comment: No iframes on the page and the link is visible when I access the site manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To invoke `click()` on the element with text as **User Cards** as the element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  User Cards
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  a[showpage='cards']>i.zzdi.zzdi-closed-caption.zzdi-hx-fw
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  //a[@showpage='cards' and normalize-space()='User Cards']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, due to differences in windows size (my machine vs. the virtual screen used by Selenium), the navbar wasn't displayed and therefore the element could not be found.

Found it out while doing a workaround - getting all elements with "a" tag, then iterating through them. Only after clicking on an extra button to make the navbar displayed, the element could be found.